# Display custom post type title as text if post thumbnail is not available

Tags: php, post-thumbnails, title

Im a little hung up here. I'm trying to write an if else statement to show either the thumbnail if its present, and if its not, show the post title. Here is my code:

```
<div id="primary" class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php 
        // the query
        $the_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'lender') ); ?>

        <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <div class="row">

                <!-- the loop -->
                <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6">

                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                the_post_thumbnail();
                       } else { ?> 

                        <?php the_title( '<h4>', '</h4>'); ?>
                      } ?>

                </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <!-- end of the loop -->

            </div> <!-- .row -->

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>
            <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>


    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

I know the issue is probably a super easy fix, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace the block in the middle of the query with this code:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
   the_post_thumbnail();
} else {  
   the_title( '<h4>', '</h4>');
} ?>
```